# combining array object properties to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects called `rate`. Within each rate object is a tags property. I would like to combine the tags from all objects into new array such that expected output is:

```
["TAG_1_2_3_4", "TAG_7_8_9_0", "TAG_4_5_6"]
```

Is there a simpler/cleaner way than using `forEach` to loop through and then push to array?

Example:

```
[
  {
    "price": "123",
    "tags": [
      "TAG_1_2_3_4",
      "TAG_7_8_9_0"
    ]
  },
  {
    "price":"456",
    "tags":[
      "TAG_4_5_6"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Any code to show?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get the `tags` and flatten them to a single array:

```js
const arr = [{"price":"123","tags":["TAG_1_2_3_4","TAG_7_8_9_0"]},{"price":"456","tags":["TAG_4_5_6"]}]

const result = arr.flatMap(o => o.tags)

console.log(result)
```

If `Array.flatMap()` is not supported, you can use `Array.reduce()` with `Array.concat()`:

```js
const arr = [{"price":"123","tags":["TAG_1_2_3_4","TAG_7_8_9_0"]},{"price":"456","tags":["TAG_4_5_6"]}]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, o) => acc.concat(o.tags), [])

console.log(result)
```

Or get all `tags` with `Array.map()`, and flatten by spreading into `Array.concat()`:

```js
const arr = [{"price":"123","tags":["TAG_1_2_3_4","TAG_7_8_9_0"]},{"price":"456","tags":["TAG_4_5_6"]}]

const result = [].concat(...arr.map(o => o.tags))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: awesome! i see flatMap is not supported in IE. Is there another way?

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: according to this, flatMap is not supported in any IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Comment: Which version of IE do you need to support?